# How exclude columns from different dataframe and then mix two of these columns?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, tidyverse

I'm trying to exclude columns from two different dataframe and then plot this different dataframe (only plot numerical values).
The dataframe examples is here (link):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVHxb.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDHyi.png)

I need plot only values from colum "Val1" vs "Val_1"
I'm using ggplot2 and tidyverse in RStudio, my columns have 727 "identification names" (Id1 and Id2, see the image please) and the respective values.

The purpose to made this is for a Scatter Plot, where the X axis is for "Val1" and Y axis for "Val_1".
Any help is welcome, thank you!
Best

Comment: Please add some sample data that can be copied and code can be tried upon.

Answer (score 0):

Converting your pictures to sample data, first

```
> dput(df1)
structure(list(Id1 = c("QJY77946", "QJY77954", "QJY77954", "QJY77962", 
"QJY77962"), Id2 = c("NP_073551", "NP_073551", "QJY77946", "NP_073551", 
"QJY77946"), Val1 = c(0.0241, 0.0119, 0.0119, 0.0119, 0.0119)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

> dput(df2)
structure(list(ID_1 = c("QJY77946", "QJY77954", "QJY77954", "QJY77962"
), Id_2 = c("NP_073551", "NP_073551", "QJY77946", "NP_073551"
), Val_1 = c(0.1402, 0.0912, 0.0439, 0.0912)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

> df1
       Id1       Id2   Val1
1 QJY77946 NP_073551 0.0241
2 QJY77954 NP_073551 0.0119
3 QJY77954  QJY77946 0.0119
4 QJY77962 NP_073551 0.0119
5 QJY77962  QJY77946 0.0119

> df2
      ID_1      Id_2  Val_1
1 QJY77946 NP_073551 0.1402
2 QJY77954 NP_073551 0.0912
3 QJY77954  QJY77946 0.0439
4 QJY77962 NP_073551 0.0912
```

You can try this

```
df1 %>% inner_join(df2, by = c("Id1"="ID_1", "Id2"="Id_2")) %>% ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = Val1, y=Val_1))
```

[image]